# Prove that a proposed algorithm gives an optimal solution of the optimization problem.

Tags: optimization, algorithms, recursive-algorithms

We have $N$ queues.
Each of the queues contains a number of numbered ball, and the balls can be taken out in descending order.
For example, the queues can be as the follows:
[image: Queue_Fig]

I want to take $L$ balls from the queues such that the sum of the balls' numbers is as large as possible.

- Let us denote $i$th ball in the queue $q$ by $x_i^q$, e.g., $x_1^2=70$, $x_2^M=1600$.
- Let us denote the number of balls taken from the queue $q$ by $L_q$.

Then, the optimization problem is formulated as
$$
\text{maximize}\quad\sum_{q=1}^M\sum_{i=1}^{L_q} x_i^q,\qquad\text{subject to}\quad\sum_{q=1}^M L_q = L,
$$
where the decision variables are $L_1, L_2, \ldots, L_q$.

---

I made a greedy algorithm.

First, set $L_q=0$ for all $q$. Then, select a queue $k$ whose first ball has the largest number. Then, take out a ball from the queue $k$ with updating $L_k$ to $L_k+1$. We repeat these procedures until $L$ balls are taken out from the queues. Finally, $L_1$, $L_2$, $\ldots$, $L_M$ are the solution.

---

The above algorithm is intuitively supposed to give an optimal solution, but I could've not yet mathematically proved that the output of the algorithm is optimal.
Is there any way to prove the above algorithm gives the optimal solution?
I am not only an rigorous proof but also very welcome advice on the direction for the proof.

Comment: Suppose queue 1 has 5,10, queue 2 has 1, 1000 and L=2.  If I understand your algorithm correctly, it chooses 5,10 instead of 1,1000.

Comment: @saulspatz Supposing that a queue 1 has two balls with number 5 and 10, and a queue 2 has also two balls with number 1 and 1000. If we have to take out only two balls, then the optimal solution will be $L_1=1$ and $L_2=1$. Then, the objective value becomes $10+1000=1010$. (Algorithm also gives $L_1=L_2=1$.)

Comment: Okay, I had it backwards.  Your algorithm is simply to always take the largest available ball, and it clearly works.

Comment: @saulspatz Yeah, I just wanna prove its optimality rigorously and mathematically.

Comment: I still don't understand how your algorithm doesn't output $L_1=2$ and $L_2=0$ in @saulspatz 's example.

Comment: @Rchn In algorithm, the first ball is taken out from the queue. That is, the second ball becomes the first one. Sorry for my poor explanation. Hard to describe my thought well in English.

Comment: @Rchn The largest balls are taken first.  Note that the OP says the balls are taken out in descending order.  The arrows in the diagram are what confused me, I think.  I took them to mean the direction of growth of the queue, so I thought the large numbers were at the back of the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm is to always choose the largest available number.  Prove it by contradiction.  Suppose the largest available number is $N,$ and consider any solution $S$ in which $N$ is not chosen.  Replace the smallest $s \in S$ by $N$ to get a new solution $S'$.  Now $N\ge s$ because $s$ is less than the element $x$ at the head of its queue, and $N\ge x$ so that $\sum S'>= \sum S.$  Either all the elements in $S'$ are equal to $N$ or we have a contradiction.  In either, case, we see that an optimal solution must contain $N$.